# Raspberry pi live stream to youtube stopped working

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, stream, raspberry-pi3, live-streaming

I have a working setup for streaming a video to youtube with my raspberry pi 3.
It was work until yesterday. Nothing changed but I have an error when I try to start the stream.
Running the following command:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -p -hf -fps 25 -b 2560000 | avconv -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my_key
```

And get this error:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg
developers   built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1) 20170516  
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1+rpt1'
--toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared   libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101   libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101   libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101   libavdevice    57.  1.100 /
57.  1.100   libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100   libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0   libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100   libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100   libpostproc    54.  1.100 /
54.  1.100 Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo Input #0, s16le, from '/dev/zero':   Duration: N/A, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s Input #1, h264, from 'pipe:':   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my_key: Input/output error
```

It worked more over a month, but now (I don't know why) stopped working.

Can anyone help me?

Cheers,
Greg

Comment: If I scanned the error message correct, it just contains `Input/output error` besides a whole lot of configuration data. Maybe some I/O or access right issue, but with the given information I'm not sure whether somebody can help you.

Comment: Yes, the exact error only this:
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my_key: Input/output error

I just put the whole process to the question for know what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Some more information, I can save the stream to a file, everything is just fine but youtube source streaming.

Comment: **I figured it out!**
_If you have the same problem just go to youtube stream now / encoder setup / stream name/key, push the reveal button and then the reset button to get a new stream name/key string._
**Use the new key!**

Answer (score 1):

**I figured it out!**
*If you have the same problem just go to youtube stream now / encoder setup / stream name/key, push the reveal button and then the reset button to get a new stream name/key string.*
**Use the new key!**

Answer (score 0):

How to stream on YouTube with a Raspberry Pi 3b+ or higher with a Raspbian Stretch and a USB sound card?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function start_stream {
        raspivid -a 12 -n -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 25 -b 6000000 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -f alsa -ac 1 -itsoffset 5.00 -i plughw:0,0 -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAMCODE
        while [ "$?" = "1" ]; do
        start_stream
        done
        }
start_stream
```